# Python Pandas: error: missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 2

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which contains the characters `(((` I would like to replace. But I get error after doing this:

```
data = [{'Title': 'set1((("a", "b", "c")))'},
     {'Title': 'set2((("d", "e", "f")))'},
     {'Title': 'set3((("g", "h", "i")))'},
     {'Title': 'set4((("j", "k", "l")))'},
     {'Title': 'set5((("m", "n", "o")))'},
     {'Title': 'set6((("p", "q", "r")))'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

# df['Title'] = df['Title'].str.replace('set', 'M') # Works correctly
df['Title'] = df['Title'].str.replace('(((', '>>') # Not working
```

How do I solve this error in order to to replace `(((` by `>>` and `)))` by `<<`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`replace` in `pandas` lets you use `regex` and `(` has special meaning in `regex` so use `\(`

```
df['Title'] = df['Title'].str.replace('\(\(\(', '>>')
```

pandas doc: [pandas.Series.str.replace](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)

Comment: what if i want to replace `("ite)m", "")` I changed it to `("\ite)m")`still I am getting the same error.

Comment: @chandru char `)` has special meaning in regular expression so you have to use \ to remove this meaning - you have to use `\)` - `replace("ite\)m", "")`

Answer (score 15):

A more general solution would be to escape the input token using `re.escape`

```
import re
inputToken = '((('
df['Title'] = df['Title'].str.replace(re.escape(inputToken), '>>')
```